# Нow can i serialize @ConfigMapping

Tags: java, serialization, quarkus

I have a project with 3 files in Quarkus

**application.properties**

```
conf.obj[0].name=name0
conf.obj[0].code=code0
conf.obj[0].versions[0].number=1
conf.obj[1].name=name1
conf.obj[1].code=code1
conf.obj[1].versions[0].number=1
conf.obj[2].name=name2
conf.obj[2].code=code2
conf.obj[2].versions[0].number=1
conf.obj[2].versions[1].number=2
```

**AvailableConfig.java**

```
package com.example;

import io.quarkus.runtime.annotations.StaticInitSafe;
import io.smallrye.config.ConfigMapping;

import java.util.List;

@StaticInitSafe
@ConfigMapping(prefix = "conf")
public interface AvailableConfig {

    List<listObject> obj();

    interface listObject {

        String name();

        String code();

        List<Version> versions();

        interface Version {
            Integer number();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainService.java**

```
package com.example;

import io.quarkus.runtime.StartupEvent;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.event.Observes;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.json.bind.Jsonb;
import java.util.List;


@ApplicationScoped
public class MainService {

    @Inject
    AvailableConfig availableConfig;

    @Inject
    Jsonb jsonb;

    void onStart(@Observes StartupEvent ev) {

        List<AvailableConfig.listObject> config = availableConfig.obj();
        String result = jsonb.toJson(config);
    }

}
```

As a result of execution, the correct object "config" is created.
But when it is serialized, an empty json "[{},{},{}]" is obtained.

How do I properly serialize things like this?

Comment: Could you show the code of the listobject class ?

Comment: This class does not exist. In general, there is nothing more than a pom.xml.
The implementation of these interfaces is generated on the fly.
I didn't even find them in "target".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why jsonb behaves like this, but I found several solutions:

**1.** use Gson

```java
Gson gson = new Gson();
String resultGson = gson.toJson(config);
```

**2.** use jackson

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
String resultJackson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(config);
```

But I'm not sure if these options are ready for AOT-compilation in Quarkus environment.
**3.** Therefore, the best way is not to store such things in the config format, it is better to put them in your json-file.